# inner join with char index function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Ok so I'm trying to do this on SQL Server 2008:

```
select * 
from tb_contato
inner join tb_url_contato on tb_contato.RIGHT(linkurl, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(linkurl)) - 1) = tb_url_contato.url
```

This doesn't work. Any suggestions of the best way to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: You can't alias the `right` function.  Change  `on tb_contato.RIGHT` to `on right`.  If you need to alias the `linkurl` field, then do so...

Comment: yup, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

`RIGHT` is a built-in function in sql. And I assume `linkurl` is a column in the table `tb_contato`.

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_contato
INNER JOIN tb_url_contato 
ON RIGHT(tb_contato.linkurl, CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(tb_contato.linkurl))-1) = tb_url_contato.url
```

Comment: @Richard, happy to help. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without `right()`, just using `like`.  I think the logic is:

```
SELECT *
FROM tb_contato INNER JOIN
     tb_url_contato
     ON tb_contato.linkurl LIKE '%/' + tb_url_contato.url
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
      SELECT * FROM (SELECT * ,RIGHT(linkurl, COALESCE(NULLIF(CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(linkurl)), 0) - 1, LEN(linkurl))) AS NEWCOL  FROM tb_contato ) AS TA inner join tb_url_contato TB on TA.NEWCOL  = TB.url
```